# Node js storm client sending data

Tags: node.js, apache-storm

I try to set up my storm DRPC development environment in Ubuntu 14.04. I have set up Zookeeper, Nimbus, drcp server, supervisor, ui, and made them running and submitted topology. [image: Storm UI snapshot]

Then I have following node.js client codes, named NodeClient.js, when I try to run nodejs NodeClient.js, there is nothing happens. What's wrong with my Nodejs client, or something else is wrong. [image: running node client]. I suppose client.execute sends "hello world" packet to storm queue. Am I right?

========================NodeClient.js=================

```
var DRPC = require('storm-drpc-node');


var client = DRPC({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 3772,
    timeout: 1000,
    keepAlive: true,
    maxConnectCounts: 30
});



client.on('error', function(err) {
    throw err;
});



// callback way 
client.execute('spout-name', 'hello world', function(err, res) {
    if(err) throw err;
    else console.log(res);
```

## });

======Edited======
[image: supervisor started]
I started supervisor, now it runs as shown in above picture, 
In order for above NodeClient.js work, do I need to download npm install storm-node, and create spout. And shall NodeClient be modified as follows:?

===============Do I need to create spout==============

```
 var storm = require('node-storm');
 var DRPC = require('storm-drpc-node');
var client = DRPC({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 3772,
    timeout: 1000,
    keepAlive: true,
    maxConnectCounts: 30
});

var myspout = storm.spout(function(sync) {
    // For an unreliable emit:
    this.emit([fieldValue1, fieldValue2])

    // For a reliable emit:
    this.emit([fieldValue1, fieldValue2], {id: 'some unique id'})

    // Tell storm we're done emitting tuples for now
    sync()
})
.declareOutputFields(["field1", "field2"]) // declare output fields
.on('fail', function(data) {
    // Handle tuple failure
   console.log('data is not send in myspount');
})
.on('ack', function(data) {
    // Handle tuple acknowledgement
    console.log('data is in myspout');
});

client.on('error', function(err) {
    throw err;
});

// callback way
client.execute('myspout',JSON.stringify('hello world'), function(err, res) {
    if(err) throw err;
    else console.log(res);
});
```

=============Editor 2============
It seems now server part works ok. Please check UI dashboard for topology and Spout. I am using apache-storm 0.9.3's example, BasicDRPCTopology. I use remoteTopology. In the codes, there is no Spout. I am wondering where this spout in dashboard comes from? How could I using Nodejs as Spout?
[image: new topology]
[image: spout]

//Commmand to submit topology
./storm jar ../examples/storm-starter/storm-starter-topologies-0.9.3.jar storm.starter.BasicDRPCTopology callstatio

=======================BasicDRPCTopology============

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    LinearDRPCTopologyBuilder builder = new LinearDRPCTopologyBuilder("exclamation");
    builder.addBolt(new ExclaimBolt(), 3);

    Config conf = new Config();

    if (args == null || args.length == 0) {
      LocalDRPC drpc = new LocalDRPC();
      LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();

      cluster.submitTopology("drpc-demo", conf, builder.createLocalTopology(drpc));




for (String word : new String[]{ "hello", "goodbye" }) {
    System.out.println("Result for \"" + word + "\": " + drpc.execute("exclamation", word));
  }

  cluster.shutdown();
  drpc.shutdown();
}
else {
  conf.setNumWorkers(3);
  StormSubmitter.submitTopologyWithProgressBar(args[0], conf, builder.createRemoteTopology());
}
```

==================edited 3=============

I put following Java client DRPC, it does NOT work either. Are there something wrong with my client part. I attached my storm.yaml after the codes: Any hints?

`public class TestSpout` {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws TException, DRPCExecutionException {
        DRPCClient client = new DRPCClient("127.0.0.1", 3772);
        String result = client.execute("callstatio", "hello world");
        System.out.println("result is:"+result);    
    }

}
```

=========storm.yaml====

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
     - "localhost"

nimbus.host: "localhost"
storm.zookeeper.port: 2181
storm.local.dir: "/var/stormtmp/"
java.library.path: "/usr/local/lib/"
supervisor.slots.ports:
  -6700
  -6701
  -6702
  -6703

worker.childopts: "-Xmx768m"
nimbus.childopts: "-Xmx512m"
supervisor.childopts: "-Xmx256m"


 drpc.servers:
     - "127.0.0.1"
```

================Edit 4=
Starting ./storm supervisor gives following exception: Any hints?
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Integer

Comment: Storm ui shows that you have no worker and no supervisor for your topology. Try to check if storm supervisor runs correctly.

Comment: @zenbeni: Thanks for the answer. I started supervisor. But I got no luck. Do you think my NodeClient.js has some problems?

Comment: from UI dashbboard: I see following message:java.lang.RuntimeException: No DRPC servers configured for topology at backtype.storm.drpc.DRPCSpout.open(DRPCSpout.java:79) at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3373$fn__3388.invoke(executor.clj:522) at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__464.invoke(util.clj:461) at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 1):

You need to launch the DRPC storm with

```
storm drpc
```

Then add the url of the DRPC server in storm.yaml

```
drpc.servers:
   - "my.ip.com"
```

Don't forget to use

```
LinearDRPCTopologyBuilder
```

Instead of of the traditionnal 'TopologyBuilder' when you build your topology.

Check more from the documentation of storm (local mode etc)

https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Distributed-RPC.html

Comment: Yes, You are right. But I got no success with my Node.js. From UI dashboard, I see spout. But when I click spout, I found there is no emit tuple at all. I put dashboard on picture 4 and 5. I suppose now server part is working, except Nodejs client, there might be programming error.

Comment: I use apache-storm examples, in the BasicDRPCTopology, there is no spout. Why dashboard shows one spout. I try to use Nodejs as spout.

Comment: @user84592 The spout must be storm drpc server that you call from nodejs, have you tried to use the basic client in java given with Storm? If it works it means it is a nodejs problem.

Comment: Are there standalone java DRPC client? Anyway, try to use Java as client is a good way to test server part. Though our production is Nodejs as client.

Comment: I put all java client part of codes in edit 3 afterwards. It seems that it has same problem as Node.js client, program hangs there. I attached with my storm.yaml. Any hints?

Comment: Starting ./storm supervisor gives following exception: Any hints?
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Integer

Comment: can you help on this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968869/starting-distributed-rpc-server ?